# javascript data in forms with option value

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use  form control to select data from javascript

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

the bootstrap form control.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:setSlotItem(3,'SYM1');" data-value="action">
            Image 1
            <img src="/img/SYM1.png" width="25px" height="25px" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:setSlotItem(3,'SYM2');" data-value="another">
            Image 2
            <img src="/img/SYM2.png" width="25px" height="25px" />
        </a>
```

the dropdown i am using now.

```
function SlotGame() {
game = new Game();
var items = [
    { id: 'SYM1' },
    { id: 'SYM2' },
    { id: 'SYM3' },
    { id: 'SYM4' },
    { id: 'SYM5' },
    { id: 'SYM6' },
    { id: 'SYM7' },
    { id: 'SYM8' }
];
```

the javascript with the ids of the elements

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please structure your question according to the site rules, because it's very unclear what exactly do you need help with.

Comment: i have a dropdown menu with (a href) for the elements i want to have in my dropdown. I dont know how to use the a href with OPTION VALUE. instead of option value= one i want to find the element with the id SYM1

Comment: can you elaborate? I think you need to use java script dynamic!